# How to send XML POST request using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, post, afnetworking

Read tons of answers and didn't found a simple answer:
How can I send a simple XML to URL via POST and using AFNetworking ?

```
<?xml version=’1.0’ encoding=’UTF-­‐8’?>
<data>
<login>LOGIN</login>
<password>PASSWORD</password>
</data>
```

URL for example: http://example.com/API/balance.php

When I use:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"login":@"login",@"password":@"password"};
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];
[client postPath:@"balance.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
... some code ...
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

I always get XML with error from API: Error Not well-formed (invalid token) in line 1

when I used HTTP sniffer I see that Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8

May be this is problem, but I don't know exactly.
Using php with curl - get correct answer from API.

Can anybody show working example with this XML request and URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the default `[AFHTTPClient parameterEncoding]` is `AFFormURLParameterEncoding`.  Unfortunately, there is no such encoding as `AFXMLParameterEncoding`, so I'd create the XML manually and set it on a `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];

NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=’1.0’ encoding='UTF-­‐8'?><data><login>%@</login><password>%@</password></data>", user, password];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"autenticacao" parameters:nil];
req.HTTPBody = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFKissXMLRequestOperation *op = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:req success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {

    NSLog(@"%@", XMLDocument);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:op];
```

I'm also using [AFKissXMLRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation), an extension to `AFNetworking` that makes easier to parse XML on responses.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcelo. It really helps me with some changes. (I removed from "<? xml..." part of string "encoding='UTF-8'" and it worked )

Comment: AFKissXMLRequestOperation extension is officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

On your `client`, be sure to set the type of request operation to use:

```
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];
```

Comment: Nothing change, The same API error and Header has Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8